# Выборка по условию

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте! Такой вопрос... Есть `TABLE1(NumberID,DataStart,DataFinish,Title)`
Пример заполнения:

```
01,2005-01-01,2005-01-10, Третья
01,2006-01-10,2006-01-30, Вторая
01,2008-03-10,2008-03-20, Первая
```

Т.е. есть несколько строк для одного и того же `NumberID`. Как мне вытащить в процедуре только ту, где Title=первая?

Или если бы для 01 было бы две строки, то тогда вытащить с Title=второй, то есть тот, где дата максимальная?

никак не пойму, пытался как-то через MAX(DataStart), но не получилось...

Comment: Какая бд ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.* from TABLE1 a inner join 
   (select NumberID, max(DataStart) as DataStart
   from TABLE1 group by NumberID) b 
   on a.NumberID = b.NumberID and a.DataStart=b.DataStart;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE Title='Первая'
```

+ советую поле **NumberID** сделать **AUTOINCREMENT**

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 ORDER by DataStart DESC limit 0,1  // вытащить последнюю дату
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE Title='Первая' 
вот это мне не подойдет! если будет две строки и там title будет вторая и третья, то мне надо вытащить со ВТОРАЯ...

Comment: и что такое вообще limit???

Comment: Ну про limit то может в нете почитать сможешь?

Чтож вы лентяи такие. Все за вас пиши и рассказывай, мы не учителя - мы так общество по интересам, хотим ответим, направим на путь истинный, но писать и подробно рассказывать что и как - это перебор.

\+  вопрос вообще получается задан некорректно, выразить мысли нужно точнее.